# What is the solution for DSO (Dynamic Shared Object) missing from command line error?

Tags: c++, linux, command-line, linker, command-line-arguments

*Hi, I’m working on a project which worked fine on previous server. After transferring it to a new remote server I added following dependencies to recent server:*
libglibmm-2.4-dev
libglibmm-2.4-dev
libgtkmm-2.4-dev
libxml++2.6-dev
libglib2.0-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libcurl4-gnutls-dev || libcurl4-openssl-dev
libmysqlclient-dev
libmysql++-dev

*The new server information which I got via **uname –a** command is:*
Linux example.com 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
*and I don’t have access to previous server in the case of giving some information about it.*

*This program has a written **Makefile** for executing as below:*
CXXFLAGS=-O2 -march=native -pipe
HEADERS=../libpicartia/config.hh ../libpicartia/mysql.hh ../libpicartia/rand.hh

mosaic: mosaic.o main.o options.o slice.o cluster.o pixel.o gallery.o utility.o   ../libpicartia/libpicartia.a
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -o mosaic mosaic.o main.o options.o slice.o cluster.o pixel.o   gallery.o utility.o `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4 libxml2.6 --libs`   -lmysqlpp -L../libpicartia/ -lpicartia

cluster.o: cluster.cc cluster.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c cluster.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 --cflags`

gallery.o: gallery.cc gallery.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c gallery.cc `pkg-config gdkmm-2.4 libxml2.6 --cflags`

mosaic.o: mosaic.cc mosaic.hh slice.hh cluster.hh pixel.hh gallery.hh utility.hh   types.hh $(HEADERS)
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c mosaic.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4 --cflags` -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/ -I../libpicartia/

main.o: main.cc options.hh mosaic.hh slice.hh cluster.hh pixel.hh utility.hh   types.hh $(HEADERS)
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4 --cflags` -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/ -I../libpicartia/

options.o: options.cc options.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c options.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 --cflags`

slice.o: slice.cc slice.hh cluster.hh pixel.hh utility.hh types.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c slice.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4 --cflags`

pixel.o: pixel.cc pixel.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c pixel.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 --cflags`

utility.o: utility.cc utility.hh types.hh
    g $(CXXFLAGS) -c utility.cc `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4 --cflags`

clean:
    rm -f *.o mosaic

*When I type **make** command I get this error:*
**g++ -O2 -march=native -pipe -o mosaic mosaic.o main.o options.o slice.o   cluster.o pixel.o gallery.o utility.o `pkg-config glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4 gdkmm-2.4   libxml++-2.6 --libs` -lmysqlpp -L../libpicartia/ -lpicartia

/usr/bin/ld: ../libpicartia//libpicartia.a(mysql.o): undefined reference to   symbol 'mysql_free_result@@libmysqlclient_18'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: error adding symbols: DSO   missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:5: recipe for target 'mosaic' failed**
make: *** [mosaic] Error 1

*To add DSO to my command, I also added **-lpthread** option at the end of make command like below:*
make -lpthread
*but nothing has changed and I still get the same error.*

*Also, because I am a new member to this company and previous developers left no manual for the project and they just gave me this **hint** to run the program:*
With following command line, user can create a photo mosaic using Album   (gallery) of g001001_happyfac     -e 70 means enhancements upto 70 ....  -a is   for album..

example/mosaic/mosaic —master-path   /var/www/example.com/orders/master/danpink.jpg —mosaic-path   /var/www/example.com/download/danpink.jpg -e 70 -a g001001_happyfac -v -s

mosaic -m u001001_cyvrgke5.jpg
—mosaic-path /path/to/target/mosaic -e 70 -a g001001_bikini01 -v -s 75 -c 100

*and when I am trying commands below to follow the only hint I have:*
./example /mosaic/mosaic --master-path example/Nelson-Mandela.jpg --mosaic-path   example/MyMosaics/ -e 70 -a g001001_flowers1 -v -s
*or*
./example/mosaic/mosaic --master-path example/Nelson-Mandela.jpg --mosaic-path   example/MyMosaics/ -e 70 -a g001001_flowers1 -v -s
*I get this error:*
**-sh: ./example/mosaic/mosaic: No such file or directory**

*Thank you for your help in advance,

Bahareh*

Comment: Please edit your post with clarification or explaination of your definition of *DSO*.

Comment: Normally a DSO is a 'dynamic shared object', in other words a shared library or DLL.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think as Paul mentioned DSO here means dynamic shared object.

Comment: What's the difference between a shared object (*.so*) and a dynamic shared object?  I thought shared libraries on Linux were SO.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think there are two ways in which a library is shared, static and dynamic.
In statically linked library the code of library is referenced at compile time and the result executable will be bigger.
But in dynamically linked libraries the code of library is referenced at run time and resulting executable will be smaller, so at run time this will need the library to reference the library related symbols.  My question is something else though.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I could solve the problem by myself. I put the solution for someone who may have similar problems.
The reason of first error was -lmysqlclient was missed from Makefile. It should be located between -lmysqlpp and -L at 5th line of Makefile.
The second error was because I didn't have execute permission for Makefile.